# Rails 4 - Route error for video_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, video, paperclip

In rails 4.2.4, I am using `paperclip` gem for video file uploads. After uploads a video file, I am getting one route error while displaying it.

```
No route matches [GET] "/videos/User_1/3/sample.webm"
```

Actual file path is `/home/shruthi/Projects/Test/videos/User_1/3/sample.webm`

Below lines were added to config/application.rb

```
config.assets.enabled = true
config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/videos"
```

In model,

```
has_attached_file :document,
:path => "#{Rails.root}/videos/:user_id/:event_id/:basename.:extension",
:url => "/videos/:user_id/:event_id/:basename.:extension",
:storage => :filesystem

validates_attachment_presence :document
validates_attachment :document,
:content_type=>{:content_type=>/^(video\/(mp4|avi|mpeg|ogg|quicktime|webm|x-matroska|x-ms-wmv|x-flv|3gpp))/},
:size => { :less_than =>5.megabytes }
validates :event, :presence=>true
```

In views,

```
<%= video_tag video.document.url, type: video.document_content_type %>
```

Please tell me how can I display the video file?

Comment: please provide also routes for videos

Comment: How can I give routes for it?

Comment: Routes are defined in config/routes.rb. Run rake routes in the terminal to see what has been defined.

Comment: No routes found related to video's display.

Comment: @ShruthiR `rake routes |grep video`